# Documentum docbase Icon is not getting refreshed

Tags: documentum

3 SP5 environment. In my custom application I have used  tag to populate an icon at runtime.
I worked fine for the first time but now when I am replacing the image with another image its not picking it up. Its still showing the old image.
I have cleared the dmcl cache, cleared the Work folder and restarted the tomcat container, but no success.

If i remove the image its shows the default image t_unknown_16.gif, but when replacing the image it is showing the old image only
Does anyone has any idea what could be missing? How can we replace the gif?

Answer (score 1):

If the new gif and the old gif have the same name you may just have a browser cache issue. Refresh and see what happens.